# DNN Survey module

Tags: dotnetnuke-5, dotnetnuke-module

I am have a requirement of creating a user feedback function in a DNN 5 (community edition) site, it includes about 30 MCQ questions and a couple of file attachments upload boxes. Can it be done using DNN survey module (http://dnnsurvey.codeplex.com)?
I don't have much experience with the DNN modules, will appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at some other third party module like - data springs dynamic forms - http://datasprings.com/Products/DNNModules/DynamicForms.aspx

Would be a little easier in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

Mandeeps LiveForms is the best solution.Gather user feedback and create amazing surveys with star rating, scale rating, and matrix / grid with multiple input types.

https://www.mandeeps.com/products/dnn-modules/live-forms